# Have to close file before reading it? Python

Tags: python

This program simply takes a file, deletes it, allows the user to input two lines which are put into the blank file, then prints the file.

But why do I have to close the file object and reopen it before it displays the newly added lines?

(Notice the file isn't printed in this version of the code. But if you remove the #'s it will perform correctly)

```
from sys import argv

sript, filename = argv

print "We will be buliding a new file from an %s" % filename
print "If you don't want to do this, hit CTRL_C"
print "If you do, hit and other key"

raw_input(">>>")

print "Oppening the file..."
file_ob = open(filename, "r+")
file_ob.truncate()

print "Now we will rewrite this file with the following line"
line1 = raw_input("The fist line will be :")
line2 = raw_input("The second line will be:")

print "Now we're put them into the file"
file_ob.write("\n\t>>>" + line1 + "\n\n\t>>>" + line2)

print "And now we will see what is in the file we just made"
print file_ob.read()

file_ob.close()

print "And now we will see what is in the file we just made"


#file_ob = open(filename, "r+")
#print file_ob.read()
#file_ob.close()
```

Comment: The file is buffered. When you close it, it will force the buffer to be flushed and written to the file. Consider using `with open(filename, "r+") as file_ob:` to avoid needing the close.

Comment: You can also use `os.SEEK_SET`, so closing and re-opening to read the file are unnecessary after writing.

Comment: @l'L'l: `os.SEEK_SET` is just a constant (and not a necessary one; `SEEK_SET` is the default mode). Did you mean `file_ob.seek(0)` (second arg defaults to `SEEK_SET`)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes as in [https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek). The constant is not necessary (depending on what you're doing); comment was left vague in the hope OP might `seek` for it :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File objects are buffered by default; unless you write enough data to fill the buffer, it won't write to the file until the file is flushed or closed (which implicitly flushes). This is done to avoid making lots of (expensive) system calls for small writes.  You can always force a flush directly by calling `fileobj.flush()`.

Some other notes: if the goal is to open for read/write and truncate the file, just open with mode `'w+'`, not `'r+'` followed by `truncate()`. Second, use `with` statements, so you don't accidentally fail to close the file (by omitting the `close`, or bypassing it thanks to an exception being thrown). Example:

```
with open(filename, "w+") as file_ob:
    # Don't need to truncate thanks to w+
    # Do writes/reads, with explicit flushes if needed
# When block exited by any means, file is flushed and closed automatically
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by 'expensive' system calls? Just that it uses to much computing power?

Comment: Transitioning between user mode code and OS kernel code is expensive for various reasons; there is a barrier between user code and kernel code for stability and security related reasons; calling from user mode to kernel mode involves a lot of work. You can search for information on "how system calls work" to get an idea; a complete explanation is wildly off-topic here.

Comment: @Ogough: I'll also note, "expensive" is relative. If we assume a system call has only 100 microseconds of overhead, then a single `flush` is still so fast no human would notice it. But if you were writing a character at a time, 10,000 times, and Python didn't buffer, you'd have spent a solid second on system call overhead just to write out a mere 10 KB of data; if buffering reduced that to, say, 3 "system" writes by buffering up to 4096 bytes at a time, the overhead would drop to 300 microseconds, which is invisible to the user.

Comment: That's really interesting. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.